# How to make controls fill the container in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Below is my xaml code :

```
<Window x:Class="ScoresBank.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ToolBar Height="25"></ToolBar>
    </WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <StatusBar Name="stbBottom" Height="25"
                   BorderThickness="2"
                   BorderBrush="Black">Example</StatusBar>
    </WrapPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Button Name="btnBrowseTags">TAGS</Button>
                <Button Name="btnBrowseTitles">TITLES</Button>
            </WrapPanel>
            <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="cbxCategory">
                Example
            </ComboBox>
            <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                <TextBox Name="txtKeyword"></TextBox>
                <Button Name="btnFind">Find</Button>
            </WrapPanel>
            <ListBox Name="lbxBrowse">
            </ListBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Button>Example</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Canvas>

    </Canvas>
</DockPanel>
```

And this is my current layout view : [image]

So, what I mean with filling the container are :

1. Making `lbxBrowse` to fill the mid-space of the `DockPanel` inside the left `StackPanel`.
2. Making `txtKeyword` to fill the `WrapPanel`.
3. Making `stbBottom` to fill the `WrapPanel`.

What I've tried :

1. It seems i've put them in a `DockPanel` with `LastChildFill="True"`. But it seems doesn't work.
2. I don't know about this, since it's not possible to put it into a `DockPanel` first.
3. I don't know anything about this.

I don't use fixed size, since I need them to keep neat even when resized in multiple screen resolution. The fixed size on `ToolBar` and `StatusBar` seems required, otherwise, the text will be unseen.

P.S. If possible, I prefer the solution to be XAML code, rather than the C# code. Otherwise, C# code is fine too.

Thank you.

Comment: The last child of the doc panel is the canvas, which is filling the remaining spaces.

Comment: I have another dockpanel inside the left stackpanel. But, thanks to you, I delete my left stackpanel and replace it with a dockpanel, and the listbox filled the place. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `Grid`. It is more easier to configure. Here is an example (I don't know exactly how you want to setup your layout).

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Button Margin="5" Content="TAGS"
               Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
      <Button Margin="5" Content="TITLES"
               Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
      <Button Margin="5" Content="EXAMPLES"
              Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

      <ComboBox Margin="5"
                 Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" />

      <ListBox Margin="5"
                Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" />

      <Button Margin="5" Content="EXAMPLE"
              Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

   </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the result:

[image]

With a grid you can set the height and the width of the columns and rows to a specific value (in points, pixels, cm, etc.), to column content (`Auto`) or proportional to the grid (with `*`).

Comment: I've tried grid before. Isn't it scrambled when maximized? I used `*` for every column and row before, and span it to what i needed. Is that incorrect? I need it to stay neat when maximized on all screen resolutions.

Comment: AH works wonders. I think my fault when using grid is i keep all my cells `*` sized, so when maximized, it's looked weird. Thanks! I think I'm going to try grid again.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `StackPanel` and `DockPanel` you can use `Grid` and set `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` and `Grid.RowDefinitions`. You can specify directly each row `Height` and each column `Width`. It's easier to use and it automaticly fit to content and container.